# Facebook Like, Send, Share thumbnail and object

Tags: image, facebook, object, share, facebook-like

After many tries, i am not able to get either a correct Thumbnail of image or a complete object in Facebook Like, Send and Share Divs.

These are the meta tags.

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
<meta property="id" content="619746228056373" /> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="185401314974757" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.thecampusbook.net" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="CampusBook - News, Messages, Alerts, Timeline, Academic Info for Students, Teachers & Parents through Web, SMS & Email channels" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.thecampusbook.net/images/broadcast_book_75.jpeg" />
```

Code for SHARE:

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="
    window.open(                  'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthecampusbook.net', 
    'facebook-share-dialog', 
    'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;"
    style="text-decoration:none;">SHARE</a>
```

Code for LIKE and SEND:

```
<div class=" fb-like" 
    data-href="http://www.thecampusbook.net/index.php" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"  
    style=" clear: both;        float: left;        margin: 15px 10px 15px 0;  ">
</div>
```

I will be thankful if anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all http://www.thecampusbook.net/index.php is not valid HTML document. For FB OG debug and refresh cache look into [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.thecampusbook.net/index.php).